# My oscillator of 40Khz is not giving 40Khz signal at the output

Tags: capacitor, oscillator, crystal, static-electricity, contact

I am putting a 40Khz crystal oscillator with 33Pf load capacitors.
 The problem I am facing is that as soon as I switch on the circuit, it is not giving me the pulse but as soon as i touch a metal or my hand on one of the pins, it begins to give the pulse. Is it a faulty Oscillator or I am doing something wrong. The circuit used to work perfectly fine with the other Hardware PCB I am using.

[image: This is the Circuit I am using]

[image: This is the Layout of the Circuit.]

This is a very weird problem for me. Kindly help.

Comment: R23 is far too high.

Comment: It used to work with the other PCBs. with only some its not working. Thats why I was curious. And anyways I just tried with 100K. still no effect!

Comment: Replace the "bad" crystal with a "good" crystal that oscillates on another PCB.

Comment: Try 100 ohms - 100 kohms is way too high - why did you choose that value?

Comment: @Andyaka At lower value its not retaining the pulse of 40KHz. If I put a lower value, the output is not stabilizing at 40khz, it comes for few seconds and goes away. at values on or above 100K only, it is functioning atleast better.

Comment: What's the chip you are using?

Comment: HEF4049BT: hex inverter

Answer (score 11):

Your series resistance of 150 kΩ is very high.  That's simply not giving the crystal enough drive, and drops the overall loop gain too low.  Try much lower values.

Also, check that 33 pF is a valid load cap value.  Often these low power "watch" crystals are rated for just 5-10 pF.

Basically, **read the datasheet** of the crystal.  None of the above should be a surprise.

Comment: Yes, thanks, i read the datasheet. Capacitor values are 12.5pf. But, changing that didn't change the problem. Also, the pulse is not retaining its frequency and shape if I reduce the resistance below 100Kohm

Comment: @Vik: So you read the datasheet, saw that it said to use a 12.5 pF load cap, but then used 33 pF anyway!?  Also, there shouldn't be pulses.  The output of the crystal should be a sine, and the input should be a rounded off square wave.

Comment: Yes, It should be like that but, its coming the same with 33pF and 12pF. I abide by your concept but thats not whats happening. so, it might something else which is not considered and thus the problem persists.

Comment: @Vikas: In a few instances on this page now you've been shown that you're using an infeasible/wrong value for something, then you've gone "okay but changing that doesn't fix my problem" then _kept the wrong value_. You should correct all of these mistakes. Maybe they're _all_ contributing to the problem? Even if they're not, there is no reason to wilfully use wildly wrong values. Also I'm not quite sure what "I abide by your concept" means. Good luck!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I am expecting that you are saying that with respect to the values of load cap. I had earlier used 33pF which was according to a reference design and with that it always came fine. Even in the circuits which I didn't make, same oscillator had 33pF cap. So, I decided to use the same. But when I read the datasheet, it said 12.5pF for Crystal of that part number. So, al I am saying is that my issue doesn't resolve even on correcting the mistake.

Comment: @VikasGupta, have you tried making **both** changes w.r.t. the cap and the R23?

Comment: @Catsunami Yes!

Comment: @VikasGupta  The crystal data sheet may say that 12pF load capacitance is required to hit the desired design frequency, but that doesn't mean you should use 12pF for C13, C14. Your active element may have too much gain if you're getting *pulses*. You should be seeing sinusoidal waves.

Comment: Sir, by pulses I mean square pulse/wave. I am telling what I am actually getting. And its a common practice to mention the load cap in datasheets as of my knowledge. If not then what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

It is not uncommon for that. Typically an issue of insufficient drive or incorrect drive type.

Try to lower the value of r23.